# Odd jQuery UI Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm attempting to use the jQuery UI Tabs module, but whenever I attempt to do so, I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'tabs'
```

I followed the demo's source down to the letter, and I still can't get it to work.

I'm loading the CSS locally and the JS from the Google CDN, and Chrome's Developer Tools are telling me that the browser got a `200 OK` for each JS and CSS file.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

---

Per request, I'm also adding my code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">TrafficLight!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">countr</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Future projects</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p><b>TrafficLight!</b> is an application that will temporarily turn your iPhone's screen red, yellow, or green. It's useful for providing instant, easy-to-understand feedback to anyone, especially a public speaker.</p>
        <p><b><a href="#">Download on the App Store</a></b></p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p><b>countr</b> is a basic counting application. You can use it to count baseball pitches, money, hats, anything!</p>
        <p><b><a href="#">Download on the App Store</a></b></p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p><i>Coming soon... ;)</i></p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Whoops, forgot this part of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javasctipt" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css">
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to initialize the tabs and the HTML of your tabs?

Comment: How are you loading the files, they have to be loaded in the right order, for example `jQuery.js` > `jQuery.UI.js` > `jQuery.UI.Tabs.js`

Comment: @T B: posted. @RobertPitt: I've got them loaded in the order: `jQuery.js` > `jQuery-UI.js`. Do I need to load the tabs library separately? I didn't need to do that for jQuery UI's `button()` method...

Comment: Are you using the minified version?  Usually the minified version has all the widgets included.  Could you add the javascript you are using to initialize the tabs too?

Comment: Actually, just ested and do not need the tabs as its bundled: http://jsfiddle.net/qVYH2/, Please add your `<head>...</head>` contents

Comment: @T B: D'oh. Sorry about that, posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found your problem.  In your jQuery UI script tag you have "type='text/javasctipt'" which "javascript" is misspelled.